# Confidence Interval of Categorical Data with Multiple responses

Tags: confidence-interval, categorical-data, multivariate-analysis, many-categories

What is the best practice to calculate confidence intervals for Categorical Data with multiple responses? All of the tutorials and information I find online use boolean examples.. (Do you support this candidate, yes or no? Do you like this product, yes or no?)

I would like to know how to deal with a question such as: which is your favorite food: Watermelon, Lemons, Strawberries, or Prunes? (pick one) Where I would survey a random sample of the population.

Should I simply calculate the sample percentage of "Lemons" versus the total sample size and extract the confidence interval using only that information, or is there a way to incorporate the percentages of each response in the confidence interval calculation?

Comment: Are you trying to construct an interval for the proportion that choose Lemon? Or something else?

Comment: @Glen_b I am trying to construct a confidence interval for each category, and I am wondering if there is a way to calculate the confidence interval based on data from each category, or should I just focus on "Lemon" vs "Not-Lemon" , and "Prune" vs "Not Prune" etc.

Answer (score 1):

If there is just one category of interest, e.g. lemons, there's no problem with "binarizing" it and extracting a CI for the population proportion who like lemons. However, if you do this for each category, you might end up with something misleading because the numbers of responses for each category are dependent and you are making multiple probability statements, and so the probability that each proportion lies in your interval could be very different than you might expect. You could report a "confidence region," or "simultaneous confidence intervals" that capture this dependency better. See [Sison and Glaz](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/01621459.1995.10476521).

Answer (score 0):

You should focus on lemons as a proportion of the total. The number of cases will be the total who answered all responses Watermelon, Lemons, Strawberries, or Prunes?